# How to display a specific alert with radio buttons using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with two radio buttons, "Yes" and "No", that toggles visibility of a div.

I'd like to display an alert to the user if the "No" option is selected ONLY when the "Yes" option is already selected.

If neither option has been selected and "No" is clicked, the alert should not display.

```
$('.toggle').on('change',function(){

    var showOrHide = false;

    $(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').andSelf().each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == 1 && $(this).prop("checked")) showOrHide = true;

    })    

    $(this).parent().parent().next('.group').toggle(showOrHide);    

}).change()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store the already selected value.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="Yes" name="rad" value="Yes"/>Yes<br/>
<input type="radio" id="No" name="rad" value="No"/>No<br/>
```

Javascript

```
var alreadySelected="";
$("input").click(function(){
  if(alreadySelected=="Yes")
  {
     alert("You are switching from Yes");
  }
  alreadySelected=$(this).val();
});
```

**EDIT :** As per your comment, If one radio button is already checked in the page load,use this code,

After the page loads, get the already checked item and store it in the "alreadySelected" variable. Here is the updated code

```
var alreadySelected="";
 $(function(){
    alreadySelected=$('input[name=rad]:checked').val()
 })
 $("input").click(function(){
   if(alreadySelected=="Yes")
   {
     alert("You are switching from Yes");
   }
  alreadySelected=$(this).val();
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/VMKaP/8/

Comment: This is almost perfect, but doesn't work if the "Yes" radio button is selected on page load.  If you select "No" in this case, the alert does not display. http://jsfiddle.net/VMKaP/6/

Comment: @Michael : Read the already selected value in page load. I updated my answer & the jsfiddle link to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to only apply the handler when the Yes button has been checked and remove it whenever the No button is checked.  I'm assuming both start unchecked since otherwise at least one of the buttons would be checked and your second condition would not apply.

```
$('.toggle[value="Yes"]').on('change', function() {
   $('.toggle[value="No"]').off('change');
   if (this.checked) {
      $('.toggle[value="No"]').on('change', function() {
           // show your alert
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: This is close.  It works for the first click, but the alert is always displaying after an option is selected.  See http://jsfiddle.net/HCfsy/

Comment: @Michael - you're using `val()` incorrectly.  I think you want `'toggle[value="0"]'` and `'toggle[value="1"]'` or use `eq`.  See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rar7V/  I did have an extra space in my selector, which I've now removed.

Comment: Gotcha.  Almost there.  The div is not hiding again when "No" is selected though.

Answer (score 0):

here is a trick that will do the work -
set an invisible field in the page which indicates if the "yes" button was chosen-
for ex -

```
<input type="hidden" value="no" name="isYesChosen">
```

now , when the "yes" radio is being checked - fire a function which sets the value of "isYesChosen" to - "yes".

now you can fire the toggle button only when the value of your checking input is "yes"
(add a simple if statment in the start of your jquery code).
notice me if you have any trubble